# Hotseat Animation in launcher3 (Android 13)

Tags: android

I have downloaded a project for Android Studio. A Launcher3.

After the build of it and install in my phone there is an animation of the Hotseat for 6 - 7 times. And that after use any Apps in my Phone. But it is only at the Homescreen.

Please, in which file can I change this?

Thanks

I have tried to change the workspace or the animation.